# Supervisord, Celery and Daemonization - Does my configuration respect good practice?

Tags: celery, supervisord, celerybeat

I've deployed a Django application using Apache2 and have been struggling with Celery configuration.

### 1st try:

I used systemd for daemonization of celery and celery_beat as stated in celery [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#usage-systemd). It was sort of working with this configuration (which is not advised for production)

```
ExecStart=/path/to/celery/bin/ -A proj worker
ExecStart=/path/to/celery/bin/ -A proj beat
```

But I couldn't get the "official" configuration working, something like this:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
```

Service was running but scheduled tasks didn't execute.

### Current configuration:

I've read this [article](https://medium.com/@yehandjoe/celery-4-periodic-task-in-django-9f6b5a8c21c7) (Celery 4 Periodic Tasks on Medium) advising to use supervisord. That's what I did, and my configuration files look like this

```
[program:projworker]

command=/path/to/celery/bin/-A proj worker -l info
```

So it's actually the same command as disadvised in Celery documentation.(Though for both configurations I correctly set up project dir, user and group, etc). However everything is going smoothly.

So in the end, my question is: does this actually respect good practices ? According to this [piece](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#nondaemonizing-of-subprocesses) of documentation supervisord handles daemonization but I'm actually not sure I got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, I'd recommend using multi.  The reason to use multi is that multi offers a syntax to allow you to gracefully start, stop, or restart celery workers.  That said, if you don't need that functionality or you have a good way to handle start, stop, and restart with supervisord without using multi, go ahead and do it the way you did.

[Here is the sample recommended configuration for celery beat with supervisord](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/extra/supervisord/).

Comment: Ah I knew I didn't dug enough in documentation. Thanks for detailed answer and sample of configuration, exactly what I needed !